# Cannot delete SAP Change Request due to locked objects

Tags: customization, sap-basis

I'm trying to delete a SAP CR.
I opened it for some changes. Now I don't need these changes anymore, so I deleted all the objects and I cleared all the components of my CR.

Then I tried to delete the request (it is empty now) but an error occurred:

> Cannot delete (request locks still exist)

How can I fix it? My CR is empty... Where are locks?

Comment: unless you release the request (e.g. in transaction SE10) it is locked and can't be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unlock objects in particular request you should go to

1. *SE03 (Transport Organizer Tools)* >> *Requests/Tasks* >> *Unlock objects*
2. Select target request
3. Press *Execute*

P.S. You need `S_CTS_ADMI` authorization to get this menu item activated.

Answer (score 0):

Check table TLOCK, which should contain the lock in question (field TRKORR contains the transport number).